# What is the difference in Nokogiri::HTML(html_content) vs Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html_content)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I searched in the internet and couldn't find the difference between them.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking, we expect that you'll show us where you've researched and what you've tried. If the research didn't turn up answers then say so. If what you tried didn't get anywhere after trying and trying and trying for days and days, then show what you tried and explain what errors you got and what you want to do. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 4):

Nothing. They're both convenience methods for [`Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/HTML/Document#parse-class_method).

[Here is `Nokogiri.HTML`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/html.rb#L14) ie. `Nokogiri::HTML`.

```
module Nokogiri
  class << self
    ###
    # Parse HTML.  Convenience method for Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse
    def HTML thing, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML, &block
      Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(thing, url, encoding, options, &block)
    end
  end
```

[And `Nokogiri::HTML.parse`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/html.rb#L23)

```
module Nokogiri
  module HTML
    class << self
      ###
      # Parse HTML.  Convenience method for Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse
      def parse thing, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML, &block
        Document.parse(thing, url, encoding, options, &block)
      end)
```

Comment: I always thought `.parse` figures out the content (HTML or XML) while the first one early returns if it's xml. It doesn't seem that is the case. Any ideas if it's slightly faster to use `.parse` ?

Comment: @radubogdan There should be no difference.

Comment: @radubogdan That is done when calling `Nokogiri(your_string)` or `Nokogiri.parse(your_string)`. *"Nokogiri will try to guess what type of document you are attempting to parse"* - [Nokogiri Cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet#creating-and-working-with-documents)

Comment: @3limin4t0r oh yes, I knew something like that. Cheers for the link.

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to figure out what you tried, but here's a simple test that would have showed you the delta between the two:

```
require 'nokogiri'

Nokogiri::HTML('<p>').to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html><body><p></p></body></html>\n"

Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<p>').to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html><body><p></p></body></html>\n"
```

Or, even better:

```
Nokogiri::HTML('<p>').to_html == Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<p>').to_html
# => true
```

> Any ideas if it's slightly faster to use .parse?

Easily figured out:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'nokogiri'

compare do
  nokogiri_html { Nokogiri::HTML('<p>').to_html }
  nokogiri_html_parse { Nokogiri::HTML.parse('<p>').to_html }
end

# >> Running each test 128 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> nokogiri_html is similar to nokogiri_html_parse
```

If one is *slightly faster* it's to the point of being negligible. See the [Fruity documentation](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) for an explanation.